# Wrong item being selected on click event

Tags: vuejs2

I have a list of attachments that can be removed from a page via a button (see image attachment).

[image]

However, the deletion order is not correct. Sometimes when you click a button, a different attachment is deleted and not the one that you thought you clicked.

What's happening? Does anyone know how I can fix?

Full demo code here: [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/embed/correct-attachments-not-being-deleted-nb48d)

> EditPost.vue:

```
<li>Media Attachments
  <ul v-if="attachmentsFileNames && attachmentsFileNames.length">
    <li v-for="(attachmentFileName, index) in attachmentsFileNames" :key="index">
      <a :href="'will-be-download-Attachment-Api-Url/' +  attachmentsArray.attachments[index]">
        {{ attachmentFileName }}
      </a>&nbsp;
      <button  @click.prevent="removeAttachmentItemEvent(attachmentsArray.attachments[index])">Delete me!</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

methods: {
  removeAttachmentItemEvent(item) {
    this.attachmentsToDelete.push(item);
    this.$emit("removeMediaAttachment", item);
  },
}
```

> PostDetail.vue:

```
<section v-if="editPostFormIsVis">
  <EditPost
    :post="post"
    @update="postUpdated"
    @cancel="cancelEdit"
    :attachmentsArray="attachmentsArray"
    @removeMediaAttachment="removeMediaItem"
  />
</section>

data() {
  return {
    post: {},
    attachmentsArray: [],
    attachmentsToDelete: []
  };
},
...
methods: {
  removeMediaItem(item) {
    this.attachmentsArray.attachments.splice(item, 1);
  },
}
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.splice()` accepts an index as the first argument. You are passing one of the array items

Comment: @Phil: Do you have a code example? Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Examples

Answer (score 1):

```
removeMediaItem(index) {
      this.attachmentsArray.attachments.splice(index, 1);
},
```

Pass the index in removeMediaItem emitted event method.[image]

Comment: trhanks, unfortunately I still get the same problem : https://codesandbox.io/embed/correct-attachments-not-being-deleted-9mu33

Comment: removeAttachmentItemEvent(item,index) {
      this.attachmentsToDelete.push(item);
      this.$emit("removeMediaAttachment",index);
    },

Comment: Update your API part accordingly

Comment: It still doesn't work. I must be doing something wrong. Can you form the code and send me a link of it working? Thanks.